# MySQL unknown column in field list. Caused by trigger?

Tags: mysql

This is making me doubt my knowledge on MySQL, but this is driving me crazy.

It's a real simple error:

```
Error
SQL query: 

INSERT INTO upplysingar (ID, post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES 
('', '1', 'nem_nafn', 'Bergur'), 
('', '1', 'nem_email', 'bergur@togg.is'), 
('', '1', 'nem_kennitala', '0411932639'), 
('', '1', 'asdfgfsad', 'sadfg'), 
('', '1', 'sad', 'asdsfsfgssda')

MySQL said:  
#1054 - Unknown column 'meta_value' in 'field list'
```

The table I'm trying to insert the data into is:

```
CREATE TABLE upplysingar
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    post_id int,
    meta_key varchar(50),
    meta_value varchar(50)
);
```

There are no misspelled column names and the quotas are all correct to the best of my knowledge. I've tryed "NULL" instead of the " '' " for the first column (id). I'm out of ideas, I even get the same error when I use the "Insert" tab on phpmyadmin.

Any ides how to fix this?

To clarify the use of this, I have a trigger that catches the information with the right meta_keys and puts them into another table with the corresponding post_id.

[Screenshot of Select * From upplysingar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqD3p.png)

Trigger:

```
drop trigger if exists Trg_after_insert;
delimiter $$
create trigger Trg_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON upplysingar
FOR EACH ROW

begin

SET @info = 
(
    SELECT meta_value
    FROM upplysingar
    WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_name'
);

IF @info IS NOT NULL THEN

    INSERT INTO nemendur(id, nafn, email, kennitala, post_id)
    VALUES
    ('', @info, '', '', NEW.post_id);
ELSE
    SET @info = 
    (SELECT meta_value
     FROM upplysingar
     WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_email');

    IF @info IS NOT NULL THEN

        UPDATE nemendur
        SET email = @info
        WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;

    ELSE

        SET @info = (SELECT meta_value
                 FROM upplysingar
                 WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_kennitala');

        if @info IS NOT NULL THEN

            UPDATE nemendur
            SET kennitala = @info
            WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id;
        end if;
    end if;
end if;

end $$
delimiter $$
```

Thanks in advance,
WeirdGuy

Comment: Just skip column `ID` and pass no value, it'll be automatically generated. Other than that this seems to work as expected - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nQhtU47Jit9sFC3UUfSwzL/0

Comment: did you try to remove the `id` from the insert query?

Comment: Just tried it, I get the same error I'm afraid.

Comment: @WeirdGuy then your DDL is different, it worked in db-fiddle with MySQL 5.7 as SQL engine.

Comment: Anyone know if this could be server side?

Comment: The error could be/caused by the trigger. Edit your question and add the trigger definition.

Comment: It's after insert thou, the data should still get in the table right? (adding it now)

Comment: Oh, It was there when I ran it. You're getting the copy of the query that came with the error message. Apparently it gets erased for some reason.

Comment: In your trigger, you are missing the table (ie FROM clause) in the query where you set @info. Since there's no table, there's no column meta_value. I haven't looked past that point, so there may be other issues as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO upplysingar (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES 
('1', 'nem_nafn', 'Bergur')
```

ID will auto increment.

Comment: Both comments recommended this, so I tried. Still getting the error.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of a select * from your table?

Comment: Done, almost at the bottom of the qustion.

Comment: Thanks. Im stumped. Unless you had the table created previously without that column and the schema is not updating for some reason. Try with a new table name?  Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: No worries, I'm just grateful for the time you're taking to try :). Sadly this is the new table, I have another one with the exact same problem that lead me to creating this one ;)

Comment: What happens if you create the table with a different column order?  Does it still error on that column name?

Comment: No "FROM"?SET @info = 
    (
      SELECT meta_value
      WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id && meta_key = 'nem_name'
    );